# Network controller driver won't install Debian 10

Tags: debian, network-interface, iwlwifi

I'm trying to install driver for my `Intel Wireless-AC 9462` network controller. I don't know why, but there is no info about 
available Kernel modules in `lspci -v` output. I've installed `firmware-iwlwifi` and `firmware-misc-nonfree`, then executed `modprobe iwlwifi` but nothing has changed.

**lspci -v** (network controller part)

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0074
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at b4310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1345
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 9f800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
```

**modinfo iwlwifi |tail -n 50**

```
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001204bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       4.19.0-8-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Debian Secure Boot CA
sig_key:        A7:46:8D:EF
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
signature:      22:F2:8C:71:38:1D:48:B4:F6:D5:43:29:D4:06:82:67:E8:A3:47:5E:
        BB:27:32:6C:82:16:A4:2E:F8:DB:21:6D:EB:8B:B7:1C:AB:28:AC:28:
        DA:FE:DF:29:97:0E:DE:85:87:BF:E2:C3:6F:DD:1A:B7:DC:74:B5:E4:
        B4:B7:BC:DA:73:10:3C:98:69:F1:61:A5:34:C6:95:9A:48:B7:B4:03:
        5F:65:C6:86:7B:A1:B6:18:EF:C8:38:27:6D:0A:F5:6D:99:14:DD:85:
        73:37:68:E7:7C:B1:4A:FE:C9:2A:96:A2:73:71:29:48:4B:94:6E:26:
        F9:AC:F8:52:03:D0:31:D5:A2:77:AC:E1:3A:71:CE:22:EE:BC:D9:03:
        BE:91:92:EB:C5:7E:8F:C1:F9:A0:D3:91:82:DA:0F:C9:F5:08:7A:14:
        4D:E7:6C:0C:DA:B0:7E:18:59:D0:2D:F8:CB:EC:EA:62:E7:BA:D3:D5:
        4C:FF:3D:DC:F8:AB:09:3E:91:3A:78:44:B3:F6:44:F6:6D:EC:51:83:
        11:7E:76:4D:89:60:D1:33:09:61:D9:F1:06:A0:3E:CA:9C:E4:57:B1:
        DE:AE:18:F9:2F:E6:95:D7:15:5E:16:81:62:8C:BC:07:62:73:41:89:
        2A:AF:86:07:83:0F:FF:B1:DF:91:53:67:D2:03:9E:0C
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for 22560 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I need Debian because of LUKS encryption.